# What's the difference between 1 and 7 Days Scheme in Vault?

Tags: king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

In Vault, you've 1, 7, 15 and 30 Days Scheme to earn Gold Interest. The 15 Days Scheme has 20% of interest, and 30 Days - 50%. However both 1 and 7 Days Scheme has 7%.

So what's the point of depositing your gold into 7 days scheme, if you can deposit only for 1 day and get the same interest? So apart of the number of days, is there any other difference?

[image: The Vault, King of Avalon, Day Scheme, Gold Deposit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KingOfAvalon/comments/6f0ekd/whats_the_point_of_7_days_scheme_in_vault/) and other sources (such as alliance members), you cannot use 1 day scheme if you didn't purchase anything. So basically **you need to buy at least one of the cheapest package to get the benefits from using 1 day schema**. Other people are forced to use 7 day scheme. This limitation is the only difference, as of course it's more profitable to have 7% for 1 day, than 7 days, but you need to buy some package.